# Bootstrap Menu Bar does not show up in screen resolution < 768 px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm unable to determine why the navbar link (e.g. contact and home) does not collapse and show a menu button (the menu hamburger) when the screen size gets below a certain resolution. Currently, when the screen resolution width is less than 768 px the navbar completely disappears.

I know this is realated to @media in the CSS, however, when I create a @media for a max-width of 767 px the navbar still disappears. Navbar code is show below.

Can anyone provide a solution to correct this code so that I can keep the logo shown for all screen resolutions and collapse the navbar to a menu button at screen resolutions < 768 px?

Boostrap.CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    nav ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 180px;
 }
}
```

Custom.CSS file

```
/* Main Menu */
.main-menu {
  padding: 0;
 }
 .menu-style-toggle{}
 .menu-style-toggle nav {
   opacity: 0;
   margin-right: -30px;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 .menu-style-toggle nav.menu-open {
   opacity: 1;
   margin-right: 0;
   visibility: visible;
 }
 .main-menu nav {
   float: left;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul{}
 .main-menu nav > ul li {
 position: relative;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 32px 0;
 }
 .stick .main-menu nav > ul > li {
    padding: 23px 0;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li + li {
   margin-left: 44px;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 23px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li > a i {
   display: block;
   float: right;
   line-height: 23px;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li.active > a {
   color: #dec839;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li > a::before, .main-menu nav > ul > li > a::after {
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 50%;
   content: "";
   height: 1px;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li > a::before {
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li > a::after {
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li:hover > a::before, .main-menu nav > ul > li:hover > 
   a::after {
   width: 15px;
   opacity: 1;
 }
 .main-menu nav > ul > li.active > a::before, .main-menu nav > ul > li.active > a::after {
    background-color: #dec839;
    width: 15px;
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="header-bottom sticky">
   <div class="container">  
      <div class="row"> 
      <!-- Header Bottom -->
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="/" class="logo navbar-brand"><img id="logo_img" src="img/gallery/logo-200.png" alt="logo" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="main-menu float-right">
          <nav>
               <ul>
                   <li class="steadyState"><a href="/">contact</a></li>
                   <li class="steadyState"><a href="/about">about</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The bootstrap menu works out of the box for all screen sizes. So first we have to ask does the menu work when you add no custom css of your own? Is the css shown in your question css that you've added yourself?

Comment: The CSS I showed here I added to the bootstrap.css file. I am also including the other CSS from the main-menu in case there is come issue with bootstrap that that CSS class.

Comment: Ok, when you remove all of the CSS you added yourself, the menu works on small screens correct? (a side note -- I would recommend never editing bootstrap.css  Always put your own CSS in a different file(s) e.g. in custom.css  This will help you a LOT down the road, you'll always know what CSS is your own and what is part of bootstrap itself)

Comment: Actually, the menu does not work on small screens and that is why I added the additional code. I'm real confused how to systematically trouble shot this issue.

Comment: Hmm, yes Bootstrap definitely works on small screens (it is even touted as "mobile first", meaning they really focus on mobile devices/small screens). Here's how I would recommend continuing: 1.) View the Console, are there any javascript errors? If so, that may very well be the problem. 2.) View the page source; are both the bootstrap .css and .js files there? When you click on the links to them, do they both open correctly? 3.) What *version* of Bootstrap are you using, 3 or 4? 4.) Create a very simple "hello world" webpage, does it still have the error?

Comment: 5.) Copy all of the "hello world" html into https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and fix any errors. If after doing those things you haven't discovered the error, copy *all* ofyour "hello world" page's source code into jsfiddle.net and let me know what version of bootstrap you are using. Send me the link to your jsfiddle here in a comment.